# How to receive and handle messages from a Service Bus in a parallel mode using Node js

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus, messagebroker, node-amqp

MS-(A) sends hundred of messages to a Azure service bus - topic, on the other side MS-(B) receives those messages by implementing AMQP subscribe

```
this.subscription = this.receiver.subscribe({
                        processMessage: this.onMessage,
                        processError: this.onError
                    });

async onMessage(message) {
        await this.eventHandler(message)
    }

public async eventHandler(message): Promise<void> {

      console.log('before')

      await Utilities.sleep(5000)

      console.log('after')
}
```

The result is that the messages received in a sync mode instead of parallel.
Meaning that till the handler not sends response, the other messages won't be received.
I'd expect to read more messages till go to await.

**current result:**  before (waiting for 5 sec) after

**expected result:** before before before ... after (after 5 sec)

How to implement it so messages keep received while the other are sleeping or in other words as a parallel mode?

Answer (score 1):

I found that subscribe function can have **options** as a parameter.

> subscribe(handlers: MessageHandlers, options?:
> SubscribeOptions): { close: any }

The object options of type *SubscribeOptions* contains prop *maxConcurrentCalls* which is enable to control the number of request to pull from a subscription.